Can replace radiator with heated flooring to balance need for heat in winter?
Hi & thx for reviewing this “Chicago dilemma”.  I own/live in a Chicago 2 flat graystone.
The 2nd floor heating system is space intensive - boiler in basement with pipes running up/down to 2nd floor radiator system.  Radiators in every room.
The radiators in kitchen and bathroom take up so much floor space it creates obstacles.  The bathroom seems to be the easiest to identify since it just stands there without use for 7 months out of the year.  If I remove the radiator AND install a pocket door my bathroom space can be re-designed for modern bath functions.
The question is, can I simply remove the radiator in bathroom and replace with heated flooring to balance 5 months heat is needed in the bathroom???
Thx!

It probably would not be just a simple job. Installing heated flooring is a fairly difficult job and it used warm water whereas your radiators use hot water or steam. Which do you have?
Have you considered replacing your radiator with a smaller base board heater that would utilize your existing system?
